# How to remove "IPv4 address parameter" field (optional) in a SCTP packet in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ipv4, packet-capture, sctp

I want to send a SCTP packet to a server using L2TP VPN in Ubuntu 20.04. For this purpose, I have set up my L2TP VPN and I can successfully test the connection using `ping` command. Now my `ifconfig` output is as follows:

```
enp0s31f6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet x.x.x.x  netmask 255.255.255.248  broadcast p.p.p.p
    ...

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    ...

ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1400
        inet y.y.y.y  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination q.q.q.q
    ...
```

In this output, `x.x.x.x` is my LAN IP and `y.y.y.y` is my VPN IP.

But when I send my **INIT** SCTP packet, two optional fields, i.e. **IPv4 address parameter**, is appeared in **INIT chunk** subtree in Wireshark log as follows. These parameters contain my IPs.

```
Stream Control Transmission Protocol, Src Port: a (a), Dst Port: b (b)
    Source port: a
    Destination port: b
    Verification tag: 0x00000000
    [Association index: 65535]
    Checksum: 0x06cf8029 [unverified]
    [Checksum Status: Unverified]
    INIT chunk (Outbound streams: 3, inbound streams: 3)
        Chunk type: INIT (1)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x00
        Chunk length: 52
        Initiate tag: 0xd1d6f19b
        Advertised receiver window credit (a_rwnd): 106496
        Number of outbound streams: 3
        Number of inbound streams: 3
        Initial TSN: 1216798565
        IPv4 address parameter (Address: x.x.x.x)
        IPv4 address parameter (Address: y.y.y.y)
        Supported address types parameter (Supported types: IPv4)
        ECN parameter
        Forward TSN supported parameter
```

and finally, here is the sent and received packets:

[image]

I think that **IPv4 address parameter (Address: x.x.x.x)** (my LAN IP) in my **INIT** packet, has caused to receive the **ABORT** packet from server. When I turn off my VPN, these two optional fields do not appear.

How can I remove these two optional fields in Ubuntu after turning up my VPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manual client IP assignment is required to remove "IPv4 address parameter" fields in a SCTP packet. So, the following codes is required in C++:

```
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_SCTP);
if(sock < 0)
{
    //handle error
}
struct sockaddr_in clientAddr;
memset(&clientAddr,0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
clientAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
clientAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("y.y.y.y"); 
clientAddr.sin_port = htons(a);
if( ::bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) < 0 )
{
    //handle error
}
```